# Frama-C's GUI (frama-c-gui) not installed despite installing frama-c on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: frama-c

I followed the instructions on http://frama-c.com/install-21.1-Scandium.html#installing-frama-c-on-windows-via-wsl completely to install Frama-C (21.1) using opam.

I want to use the GUI for Frama-C but when I tried executing the command `frama-c-gui`, I get the following message:

> Command 'frama-c-gui' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt
> install frama-c

I checked the folder location where the binaries of frama-c are located but there was no sub-folder called frama-c-gui there too.

I made sure to use depext to install the relevant dependencies so I'm not sure why frama-c-gui wasn't installed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems that, unfortunately, the WSL instructions are outdated and they recommend using OCaml 4.05.0 instead of 4.07.1, which is necessary for Frama-C 21. Could you please run `frama-c -version` and `frama-c -plugins` and tell us the result? You may have installed a different version of Frama-C, or a subset of its plug-ins, due to some constraint issues on `opam`.

Comment: Also, this is not an answer to your question, but [Frama-C's Mattermost](https://mattermost.frama-c.com), publicly accessible via a Github login, provides a community channel for discussions in which the feedback time may be lower than on StackOverflow. Ideally, the necessary information could be gathered there and then brought here for a definitive answer.

Comment: @anol Sorry for the really late reply. I've been down with eczema (really itchy skin) these few days which made me very unproductive (lying in bed a lot). My frama-c version is 21.1 (Scandium) and there are a lot of plugins:
Aorai, Callgraph, Dominators, E-ACSL, Eva, From analysis, Impact, Inout, Instantiate, Loop, Metrics, Nonterm, Obfuscator, Occurrence, Pdg, Postdominators, Print interface, Report, Rtegen, Scope, Semantic constant folding, Server, Slicing, Sparecode, Studia, Users, Variadic, WP

Answer (score 1):

The Frama-C `opam` package for Scandium 21.1 had a constraint that was too strong: it didn't detect that `conf-gtksourceview3` was installed, looking instead for `conf-gtksourceview`, and ended up disabling the GUI. A patch has been submitted to opam and after it is accepted, running `opam update` and then `opam reinstall frama-c` should get the GUI enabled.

Otherwise, as a quick workaround, you can run `opam install conf-gtksourceview`, to install the lablgtk2 version. It is not actually necessary for the Frama-C GUI if you already have the gtk3 version, but it will fool the opam rules so that the gui will not be disabled.

Comment: Thanks, I did this and I can now open up frama-c-gui! Are you a Frama-C developer?